# License for Consolas font

Tags: font-licensing

What is the license for Consolas font? Can it be used for commercial applications and/or embedded?

I tried to find it but couldn't find any. There's a "request quote" on the Microsoft website and that's all I could find, nowhere that says "you need to pay to use it"

Comment: While not specific to Consolas, the first paragraph of the accepted answer of the marked duplicate addresses your question

Comment: Thanks John. Sorry for not having found that before. Do I need to delete the question?

Comment: It's not problem, Albert. Your question is okay to stick around as it helps others through searching. Also, check out the link in that answer: http://www.microsoft.com/typography/RedistributionFAQ.mspx